# need a customised dialer layout in android

Tags: android

I need to develop a dialer for my android application. i need to develop an activity which uses the customised dialer.Can anybody help me out??

Answer (score 0):

put this as intent filter of your activity

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
```